# How does reddit remove the border at the bottom of the current tab?

Tags: html, css

Here's a screenshot. It's probably trivial, but I'm stumped.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: I should add that I'd like to do the same on my website. An example would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a suggestion from my side is that first inspect the things with browsers developer tools & there are many tutorials are related to this type of functionality.

I have created a example for you may be that's help you. Write like this:

```
ul{
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
ul:after{
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
li{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 10px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
li.active{
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Tj3LH/

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is not **no** border - its just one that you don't see...

Do you have a browser with integrated developer tools? ;-) For example Safari or Chrome have this cool feature "Inspect element" on the context-menu if you right click on an element - and voila: here is the solution!

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried the same trick, but the border of the inside element showed inside the element, so the text "hot" was a bit higher but the border wasn't hidden... What am I missing?

Comment: They deal with the padding at .tabmenu li a - maybe this? Post a link to your work and i may see the problem ;-)

Comment: I'll try a bit more and report back.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? How can I emulate the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by css like

```
.tabmenu li.selected a { // this the tab menu item replace it with your tab menu item name
 color: orangeRed;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid #5F99CF;// this is the color of box you need to specify
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;  // this the color of bottom border, in reddit case it is white , you can replace it with what color you have in your website has to look like it is hidden
 z-index: 100;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
    <div style="float:left;">Tab 1</div>
    <div style="float:left;border:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid white;margin-bottom: -1px;">Tab 1</div>
    <div style="float:left;">Tab 1</div>
    <br style="clear:both" />
</div>
```

[**Here's a link**](http://jsfiddle.net/cTegS/)

Long story short: `border-bottom:1px solid white;margin-bottom:-1px;` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's just tabbed navigation.

[smashing mangzine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/06/showcase-of-well-designed-tabbed-navigation/)

[An Example](http://blixt.org/articles/tabbed-navigation-using-css#section=introduction)

[Another Example](http://nontroppo.org/test/tab1.html)

[Tabs Generator](http://www.tabsgenerator.com/)

If you want to to use it for your site, it needs to be customized for it and any answer is not complete untill we see your html/css.